# WebStorm/IntelliJ: Auto-complete/-import of Vue files up the folder tree beyond site's root folder?

Tags: vue.js, intellij-idea, import, webstorm

I have the following project structure:

```
root
  -- site1
     -- src
        -- components
           -- ComponentA.vue
           -- ComponentB.vue
     -- package.json
     -- tsconfig.ts
     -- etc.
  -- site2
     -- src
     -- package.json
     -- tsconfig.ts
     -- etc.
  -- common
     -- components
        -- Component1.vue
        -- Component2.vue
     -- helpers
        -- helper1.ts
```

What works (IntelliJ auto-completes and auto-imports):

- Add ComponentA.vue to ComponentB.vue
- Add ComponentA.vue to Component1.vue (although never needed)
- Add Component1.vue to Component2.vue

What doesn't work (No suggestion while typing nor auto-import)

- Add Component1.vue to ComponentA.vue

Any idea how to let WebStorm index all these files in a way that serves that use case?

**EDIT**

If I remove package.json from site1 it works again. Any idea how to keep a package.json there but still not disrupt that connection?