# How to configure JetBrains IDE (PhpStorm or WebStorm) to autocomplete Vue components from sibling project in monorepo

Tags: vue.js, phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, auto-import

I am trying to solve a problem related to PhpStorm's and/or WebStorm's auto-import feature of Vue components.

I have a monorepo project structure (attachment 1) with a component library project and a regular app project.

The app projects depend on the component library (in `package.json`). I would like the IDE (PhpStorm, WebStorm) to suggest and auto-import components from the library.

I can achieve this only in a weird situation where I remove `package.json` from the app (see steps to reproduce).

Is there a way to configure IDE to do this?

Thank you in advance for any advice,

Dan

---

Follow-up question (if there actually is a way), can I pursue the IDE to import the components like this:

```js
import { MyButton } from '@company/foo-library'
```

instead of

```js
import MyButton from '@company/foo-library/src/components/button/MyButton.vue'
```

Regarding this issue, I've tried changing the auto-import settings in `Settings > Editor > Code Style > TypeScript/JavaScript > Imports > "Do not import exactly from"` (see attachment 5), but I never get the import I wanted (the one portrayed above) and I get:

```js
import MyButton from 'packages/foo-library/src/components/button/MyButton.vue';
```

#### Steps to Reproduce

1. Clone the repository (Attachment 4)
2. Open the project in PhpStorm (or WebStorm)
3. Open the `projects/bar-project/App.vue`
4. In template section, start typing `<MyButton>` (or `<MyInput>`)
5. IDE does not suggest anything
6. Rename (or delete) file `projects/bar-project/package.json`
7. Repeat steps `3-4`
8. IDE suggests components and after confirmation automatically adds import

#### Related issues

I believe this is the same issue someone had been trying to resolve on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58582103/webstorm-intellij-auto-complete-import-of-vue-files-up-the-folder-tree-beyond).

#### Expected Result

IDE suggests and auto-imports components as when the `package.json` in `bar-project` is not there.

#### Actual Result

No component suggestion happening.

---

**Attachment 1 (monorepo structure)**

```
.
├── packages
│   └── foo-library # <-- Default Vue app created via npm create vue@latest (with TS enabled)
├── packages.json   # <-- See Attachment 2
└── projects
    └── bar-project # <-- Default Vue app created via npm create vue@latest (with TS enabled)
```

**Attachment 2 (package.json)**

```json
{
  "name": "monorepo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "John Doe",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": [
    "packages/foo-library",
    "projects/bar-project"
  ]
}
```

**Attachment 3 (YT screencast)**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WZPCp6V9GvM

**Attachment 4 (MRE on GitHub)**

https://github.com/DanCharousek/mre-phpstorm-vue-components-import

**Attachment 5 (IDE settings)**

[image: IDE Settings]

Not much. The only thing that seems to be working is to remove the `package.json` in the project using the UI library which is a no-go.

Comment: I've checked this with other editor (VSCode + Volar) and it doesn'tprovide any completion/auto-import either.I believe that the problem is that your project doesn't actually depend on your library, these are 2 separate independent modules

Comment: I forgot to add the dependency in the MRE repo (I've pushed the update), but the issue ramins the same (in PHPStorm/WebStorm). Did not try VSCode.